# Difference between 'is started', has started, has been started, and has gotten started

Tags: tense, verbs

What is the difference between these sentences :

> 1) The show has started.
>   2) The show is started.
>   3) The show has been started.
>   4) The show has gotten started.

Answer (score -2):

Another way to phrase these sentences would be:

1. the show is not finished yet
2. someone or something has started the show just now
3. someone or something has started the show in (not so distant) past
4. the show has really started!

I'm not an expert in explaining this in fancy terms, but I hope you get the difference from these examples.